# Force close when get values from sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

It's my first time to dev android, also SQLite. I follow 
some tutorials to get values from SQLite. This is my code:

**Edit:**

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        myManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test);

    }
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        latitude = ((Double) location.getLatitude()).toString();
        longitude = ((Double) location.getLongitude()).toString();
        date = getDate();
        time = getCurrentTime();

        if (location != null) {
            if (checkInternet()) {

                String s = "";
                s += "\tLatitude:  " + latitude + "\n";
                s += "\tLongitude: " + longitude + "\n";
                s += "\tDate: " + date + "\n";
                s += "\tTime: " + time + "\n";

                tv.setText(s);
                //lookupData();

                }

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "network connection is not available",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                keepSQLite();

            }
        }
    }

    public void keepSQLite() {
        try {
            locationDB = openOrCreateDatabase("locationDB", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            createTable();
            insertTable();
        } catch (SQLiteException se) {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(),
                    "Could not create or Open the database");
        } finally {
            locationDB.close();
        }

    }

    private void createTable() {

        locationDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + "ben_logs_boss"
                + " (username VARCHAR, " + " date VARCHAR, " + "time VARCHAR, "
                + " lat VARCHAR, " + " lng VARCHAR);");
    }

    private void insertTable() {
        locationDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + "ben_logs_boss" + " Values ("
                + "ben" + "," + getDate() + "," + getDate() + ","
                + getCurrentTime() + "," + latitude + "," + longitude + ");");
        Toast.makeText(this, "insert", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    private void lookupData() {
            **String DB_PATH = "/data/data/test.test.test/databases/";
        String DB_NAME = "ben_logs_boss";
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        locationDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);**
            cursor = locationDB.rawQuery("SELECT lat,lng FROM " + "ben_logs_boss",
                    null);

            if (cursor != null) {
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lat"));
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lng"));

                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
                cursor.close();
                }
                locationDB.close();
            }
```

When application run until the step that call this method, force close occurred.
I don't know why. Anyone can tell me the mistake(s) ? Thank you.

**Update Logcat:**

**When it call lookupData():**

```
08-10 14:48:12.289 I/ActivityManager(  129): Displayed test.test.test/.TestActivity: +454ms
08-10 14:48:42.843 E/Database(22387): sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data/test.test.test/database/ben_logs_boss.sqlite", &handle, 1, NULL) failed
08-10 14:48:51.425 E/InputDispatcher(  129): channel '40855ac0 test.test.test/test.test.test.TestActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
08-10 14:48:51.425 E/InputDispatcher(  129): channel '40855ac0 test.test.test/test.test.test.TestActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

---

**when it call keepSQLite():**

```
08-10 14:50:29.605 E/TestActivity(22497): Could not create or Open the database
08-10 14:50:31.753 V/WindowManager(  129): isSystemKeyEventRequested() is called keyCode = 3 componentName = ComponentInfo{test.test.test/test.test.test.TestActivity}
08-10 14:50:32.253 E/Database(22610):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
08-10 14:50:32.253 E/Database(22610):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.execute(SQLiteStatement.java:61)
```

Comment: Please post your logcat, there should be an exception logged.

Comment: where are you initializing locationDB?  From the looks of this it would be possible to try and run rawQuery on a null or closed database?

Comment: How can I get the logcat? because it works only when it got the location. So, I test on a real android mobile to receive the location.

Comment: You can simulate location in the emulator, or get the logcat by pluggin in the phone and pulling it.

Comment: @Bob I initialized outside methods like this : private SQLiteDatabase locationDB = null; Yes, I closed the database once after insert it.

Comment: @Bob I already edited my code. Please see above, thank you so much.

Comment: You are still closing the database and not opening it before trying to use it?

Comment: Yes, it caused by never known. Minute ago, I searched an example to open it then tried that, force close still occurring. May be wrong code to open it.

Comment: @alextsc,Titus,Otra I already posted log above.

Comment: @Bob I edited few lines in looyupData(). I tested it, force close also.

Comment: does the folder /data/data/test.test.test exist see [this](http://sree.cc/google/android/creating-sqlite-database-tables-in-android) example on how to create a database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you are missing your database extension ie(.sqlite)

```
String DB_NAME = "ben_logs_boss.sqlite";
```

Comment: I already posted above, I just found the problem start since it call method to create database.